# VS 2010 Web Service project template missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services

This may be a silly question, but I can't find the web service application template when I try to create a new project.

Comment: Do you have the "Visual Web Developer" component installed? Go into maintenance mode in "Add/Remove Programs" in Control Panel, click "Change" and look at the list.

Comment: Try look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345498/asp-net-web-service-application-missing-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a full install on ultimate; it is still there.

Comment: Is it only available on Ultimate?  I have Premium installed.

Comment: Unsure - What do you see here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\WebService.zip ???

Comment: WebService.zip is not showing on a full install of Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Answer (score 6):

You propably want a WCF Service Project: New Project -> Visual C# (or Visual Basic) -> WCF Service Application.

Comment: Does that "translate" to web service as seen in previous versions of .NET?

Comment: Yes - the old web service project type (.asmx files) has been deprecated.

Comment: .ASMX services is based on the SOAP protocol. You can still create SOAP webservices with WCF, it is just configured using a concept known as endpoints and bindings. This way you can write a service once, and have multiple endpoints and protocols.

Answer (score 6):

I've just struggled with this one myself.

It's still there buried in specific options.

- New Project -> Visual C# (or VB) -> **Web** (important)
- Make sure the .NET Framework Filter is set to **3.5 or lower**

The project template is called ASP.Net Web Service Application

Counter intuitively it doesn't show up if you select the broader menu: New Project -> Visual C#