# How can I create a .NET 4.0 web service project in Visual Studio 2010 Pro?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, iis, .net-4.0, separation-of-concerns

The Web Services template isn't in the .NET 4.0 projects list--only .NET 3.5, but my service needs to depend on a .NET 4.0 assembly with my model/database functions. That assembly depends on 4.0, because of the data provider required (dotConnect for MySQL)

The web service will need a reference to this business logic assembly so it can pass its arguments to said assembly and blindly return. But, can I run the web services project in a .NET 4.0 application pool without any problems with the data provider?

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional, not Ultimate (which I've read has the template)--is there any way around this?

Comment: Why do you want to create an ASMX web service instead of using WCF?

Comment: I have Ultimate, and I still dont see the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 4.0 you have the WCF framework. Try this one.

Answer (score 2):

See this related article: [Asp.Net Web Service Application missing in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345498/asp-net-web-service-application-missing-in-visual-studio-2010)