# WCF Service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a wcf service project in VS 2010, but I cannit find the project template "WCF Service". Isn' t supported in all editions of VS? I have VS 2010 ultimate. How can I add this template in my programming environment?

Comment: Which edition of vs2010 you are using.You can check the features for different editions here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you selected .NET framework version 4 in New Project dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your system that under below path **WebWcfService.zip** is there ?
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033

If not then VS2010 is not installed correctly.

Comment: There is only WfcService.zip. How can I add WebWfcService?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345498/asp-net-web-service-application-missing-in-visual-studio-2010

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/60cb1c63-0132-471f-b0fc-0b2687c44e0a

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this articles instructions to restore all the default templates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx